# Permalinks with Ruby on Rails (dynamic routes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am currently developing a blogging system with Ruby on Rails and want the user to define his "permalinks" for static pages or blog posts, meaning:

the user should be able to set the page name, eg. "test-article" (that should be available via /posts/test-article) - how would I realize this in the rails applications and the routing file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the `to_param` method in the Model indeed is required/convenient, like the others said already:

```
def to_param
  pagename.parameterize
end
```

But in order to find the posts you also need to change the Controller, since the default `Post.find` methods searches for ID and not pagename. For the show action you'd need something like this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.where(:pagename => params[:id]).first
end
```

Same goes for the other action methods.

You routing rules can stay the same as for regular routes with an ID number.

Answer (score 4):

for user-friendly permalinks you can use gem 'has_permalink'. For more details http://haspermalink.org

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to do it this way:

Put the following in your Post model (stick it at the bottom before the closing 'end' tag)

```
def to_param
  permalink
end

def permalink
  "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
end
```

That's it.  You don't need to change any of the find_by methods.  This gives you URL's of the form "123-title-of-post".

Comment: This is bad SEO practice, as Google sees the first words in a URL as more important than the latter

Comment: @Houen do you suggest removing the ID? Surely a few extra digits won't make too much difference/ Do you have any links to stuff that makes this clearer? Is this the same for all search engines (yahoo, bing etc) Thanks

Comment: Its acutally not that much about digits, as it is about word count, and a dash is seen as a word separator by Google. The first words carry the most SEO weight. Sorry, no references of this, it was somthing the speakers told us at Google IO 2010

Answer (score 2):

You can use the friendly_id gem. There are no special controller changes required. Simple add an attribute for example slug to your model..for more details check out the github repo of the gem.

Answer (score 1):

The [#63](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) and [#117](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages) episodes of railscasts might help you. Also check out the resources there.

Answer (score 0):

You should have seolink or permalink attribute in pages' or posts' objects. Then you'd just use `to_param` method for your post or page model that would return that attribute.

`to_param` method is used in `*_path` methods when you pass them an object.

So if your post has title "foo bar" and seolink "baz-quux", you define a `to_param` method in model like this:

```
def to_param
  seolink
end
```

Then when you do something like `post_path(@post)` you'll get the `/posts/baz-quux` or any other relevant url that you have configured in `config/routes.rb` file (my example applies to resourceful urls). In the `show` action of your controller you'll just have to `find_by_seolink` instead of `find[_by_id]`.