# Rails: How to build a url with redirect_to and routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

In my rails project i wanna use urls like this

```
mysite.com/controller/title/action
```

instead

```
mysite.com/controller/id/action
```

How can i now build a redirect to it, 
with the following line

```
redirect_to :action => "show"
```

it redirects to the id version, how do i have to customize the line to redirect to the url with the title?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077032/permalinks-with-ruby-on-rails-dynamic-routes) provides some solutions to implement permalinks in Rails.

Comment: Hi, i don't know if this is exactly what i'm searching for. Permalink sounds very static. But the redirect that i posted is within a "update" action, it should simply show the just edited and updated record. But since i try to use seofriendly urls with titles instead ids i dont' succeed to redirect_to the just edited record to show, it redirects to the url with id. I guess there should be a more dynamically solution?

Comment: The id of the model is generated using the `to_param` method. If you follow the instructions in the post I showed you, you'll have Rails to dynamically generate the right path for you.

Comment: `to_param` is a model method, not a controller. Please make sure you read and you understand the links I posted before trying to write code.

Comment: i read it but it guess this is a bit to advanced at the moment, isn't there a much simpler solution, somehow like this? redirect_to :action => "show", :id => bookmarks.title