# How to setup a route like /article/article_name_here

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to setup a route like:

```
www.example.com/article/article_name_here
```

So the parameter is 'article_name_here' that I want to pass to the article_controller, and the action get_by_name.

Comment: What version of Rails? 2 or 3?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077032/permalinks-with-ruby-on-rails-dynamic-routes

Comment: nice link, but doesn't go over the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard resources route will do the job. Instead of a number in params[:id], you should expect a string.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following url https://github.com/bumi/find_by_param

This plugin helps to creating urls like which you asked.

Thanks,

Ramanavel Selvaraju