# Routing without the model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

Using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077032/permalinks-with-ruby-on-rails-dynamic-routes) and [railscast 63](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) I've got my articles routed to articles/article_permalink.

I'd like them to be accessible without the model name in the url so my-domain.com/article_permalink routes directly to the article.  I'd only want this to happen on the show action.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like ...

(in routes.rb)

```
 match '/:id' => 'articles#show', :via => 'get'
```

(needs to be last, or towards the end of the routes as it can match requests intended for other routes)

To change the article_path(...) helpers, "as" might help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers

Or you can add a helper for that specific path.

Comment: That works straight away thanks.  "as" seems to be for rerouting sign-up to new or images to photos etc - I can't see how I would use it to miss out the model name entirely.  Do you have any suggestions on how to make link_to show the permalink, rather than articles/permalink.

Comment: You can add a article_path helper ... I think that's what is called to generate the url.

I'd investigate that :as option, I still think that might do what you want, though I'm not positive. And make sure that doesn't interfere with your other article paths (update, delete, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want the model tied to the route "articles/article_permalink" to be dynamic based upon which is article is selected from a list?

Would you be open to appending a model ID to the end of the URL as a query string?  A more complicated approach would be to have your links POST, with the model ID as a hidden input field.  Your controller could determine if it was accessed via get/post, and handle it accordingly, but that doesn't feel right.

Regardless, when the controller action is fired up based upon a request to "articles/article_permalink", it has to know which model to fetch.  With HTTP being stateless, something has to be passed in.  You could get fancy and write JavaScript to fire one AJAX call, set a session var, and then fire the GET, but that's messy.

I hope I understood the question...

Comment: [Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).