# Change paths for link_to missing out the model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I've managed to get my routes set up (with help from these questions [Routing without the model name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729270/routing-without-the-model-name) and [Permalinks with Ruby on Rails (dynamic routes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077032/permalinks-with-ruby-on-rails-dynamic-routes))  so that articles can be accessed via `my-domain/permalink` rather than `my-domain/articles/permalink` or, the original `my-domain/articles/id`

Now I would like to make the paths that the link_to helper gives point to `/permalink` rather than `/articles/permalink`.  I've looked at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers and see how I could redirect to eg. `/images/permalink`, but can't see how to have no model name present.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `:as` on a `match ...` line in your routes file will make this work (it operates a little differently from using `:as` on a `resources ...` line):

```
match '/:id' => 'articles#show', :as => "article_permalink", :via => 'get'
```

Then you can do:

```
link_to "Show", article_permalink_path(article)
```

See [Naming Routes in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)